# HTML Image Maps - Is there an easy way to create and modify them?

Tags: html, image, imagemap

Starting out with a given image, I would like to be able to trace polygons on the image and then export the result as an HTML image map.

What would also be nice is to be able change the scale of an existing image map, thereby changing the size of the polygons and shapes.

Is there a program that anyone knows of that has these features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many program do this. It is to time consuming doing complicated maps manually.
I know [coffeecup](http://www.coffeecup.com/image-mapper/) is a used tool for this.

Comment: Cool. $29 is ok - free would be better. I probably only need this once so I suppose I could download the demo.  Anyone know if this handles my scaling problem?

Answer (score 3):

*What would also be nice is to be able change the scale of an existing image map ..*

I wrote a Javascript image map resizer, it's [here.](http://blog.outsharked.com/p/quick-tricks.html) Just paste in your HTML and it will return the scaled image map. You must include "height" and "width" attributes for the original image in the HTML. (This is a quick and dirty tool, it doesn't actually do anything other than parse the HTML you've pasted in. It uses those attributes as the base of calculations).

You may also be interested in my jQuery plugin [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) which can resize image maps dynamically among other things.

Answer (score 2):

I use this site https://www.image-map.net/  to trace polygons on the image and then export the result as an HTML image map.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32108688)

Answer (score 1):

I use this [site](http://www.image-maps.com/) it's fairly good for quickly making image-maps