# How To Make Image Map <Area> Tag Have Background Color

Tags: php, html, image, dictionary, area

I am trying to make some of the areas green and some of the red for a map project I am working on. I can't figure out how to get an `id="100101"` to be a transparent green and `<area  id="100102"`a transparent red. any help would be appreciated!! :-)

```html
<html> 

<map name="floorplanfp">
<area  id="100101" title="1" href="../carry.php?id=1001002" shape="rect" coords="52,3,239,187" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  data-maphilight='{"alwaysOn":true,"stroke":false,"fillColor":"efb1a6","fillOpacity":"0.3"}'/>
<area  id="100102" title="2" href="../carry.php?id=1002" shape="rect" coords="241,4,360,100" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100103" title="3" href="../carry.php?id=1003" shape="rect" coords="240,101,359,248" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100104" title="4" href="../carry.php?id=1004" shape="rect" coords="52,225,163,391" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100105" title="5" href="../carry.php?id=1005" shape="rect" coords="243,258,354,314" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100106" title="6" href="../carry.php?id=1006" shape="rect" coords="48,389,206,547" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100107" title="7" href="../carry.php?id=1007" shape="rect" coords="208,389,356,547" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100109" title="9" href="../carry.php?id=1009" shape="rect" coords="358,394,447,520" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100108" title="8" href="../carry.php?id=1008" shape="rect" coords="353,180,621,393" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100110" title="10" href="../carry.php?id=10010" shape="rect" coords="449,391,622,524" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100111" title="11" href="../carry.php?id=10011" shape="rect" coords="618,185,953,395" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  id="100112" title="12" href="../carry.php?id=10012" shape="rect" coords="617,390,954,551" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>
<center>
<img src="../img/testfloorplan.jpg" width="1000" height="576" usemap="#floorplanfp"/>
</center>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be a pretty challenging task. There are very few plugins that I use these days, but when I need an interactive area map there is no point re-inventing the wheel.

[ImageMapster jQuery Plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/ImageMapster/default.aspx?what.html)

[Beginner Introduction](http://members.shaw.ca/sites/AbsoluteBeginners/beginner1.htm)

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/Wvzgj/)

---

```js
var basic_opts = {
    mapKey: 'state'
};

var initial_opts = $.extend({},basic_opts, 
    { 
        staticState: true,
        fill: false,
        stroke: true,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        strokeColor: 'ff0000'
    });

$('img').mapster(initial_opts)
    .mapster('set',true,'CA', {
        fill: true,
        fillColor: '00ff00'
    })
    .mapster('snapshot')
    .mapster('rebind',basic_opts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>

<img src="https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/raw/master/examples/images/usa_map_720.png" 
usemap="#usa" style="width:400px;height:247px;">
<map id="usa_image_map" name="usa">
    <area href="#" state="TX" full="Texas" shape="poly" coords="259,256,275,257,298,258,296,275,296,288,296,289,299,292,301,293,302,293,302,291,303,293,305,293,305,291,307,293,306,295,309,296,311,296,314,296,316,298,317,296,320,297,322,299,323,299,323,301,324,302,326,300,327,300,329,300,329,302,333,304,334,303,335,300,336,300,337,302,340,302,343,303,345,304,347,303,347,301,350,301,351,302,353,300,354,300,355,302,358,302,359,300,360,300,362,302,364,304,366,304,368,305,370,307,372,305,374,306,374,314,374,321,375,329,376,331,377,334,378,338,381,341,381,344,382,344,381,350,379,354,380,356,380,358,380,363,378,365,379,368,374,369,367,372,366,374,364,375,362,376,362,377,358,380,356,382,352,385,347,386,343,389,342,390,338,392,335,393,332,397,329,397,329,398,330,400,329,404,329,407,328,410,327,413,328,415,329,420,329,425,331,426,330,428,328,429,324,426,320,425,319,425,317,425,314,423,310,422,304,419,302,417,302,412,299,411,299,409,299,409,299,406,299,406,298,405,299,402,298,400,296,399,293,396,290,392,287,389,287,388,284,379,283,376,282,374,282,374,278,370,275,368,275,367,274,365,269,365,263,364,261,362,258,364,255,365,254,367,253,370,250,374,248,376,246,375,245,374,243,374,241,372,241,372,239,371,236,369,230,363,229,360,229,354,227,350,226,347,224,347,224,345,221,344,219,342,214,337,213,335,210,332,209,329,207,327,206,327,205,323,211,324,232,326,253,327,254,310,257,270,259,256,260,256">
    <area href="#" state="TX" shape="poly" coords="332,426,331,421,329,416,329,410,329,404,332,399,335,395,337,393,338,393,334,398,331,403,329,407,329,411,329,416,332,421,332,425,332,425,332,426">

    <area href="#" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" shape="rect" coords="512,29,586,44">
    <area href="#" state="VT" full="Vermont" shape="rect" coords="543,49,586,62">
    <area href="#" state="MA" full="Massachusetts" shape="rect" coords="515,68,585,80">
    <area href="#" state="RI" full="Rhode Island" shape="rect" coords="650,149,711,161">
    <area href="#" state="CT" full="Connecticut" shape="rect" coords="655,167,711,179">
    <area href="#" state="NJ" full="New Jersey" shape="rect" coords="656,185,711,198">
    <area href="#" state="DE" full="Delaware" shape="rect" coords="665,204,711,216">
    <area href="#" state="MD" full="Maryland" shape="rect" coords="667,223,711,235">
    <area href="#" state="DC" full="District of Columbia" shape="rect" coords="654,239,711,252">
    <area href="#" state="WV" full="West Virginia" shape="rect" coords="649,257,711,270">
    <area href="#" state="SC" full="South Carolina" shape="poly" coords="551,314,551,314,548,314,548,312,547,310,545,308,544,308,542,304,540,299,537,299,536,297,535,295,533,293,532,293,530,290,528,289,524,287,524,287,523,284,522,284,520,280,518,280,515,278,513,277,513,276,514,275,515,274,515,272,520,270,526,267,531,266,543,266,545,267,546,270,549,269,559,269,560,269,570,275,577,281,573,284,572,289,571,293,569,294,569,296,567,296,566,299,563,301,562,303,561,304,558,306,556,307,557,309,553,313,551,314">
    <area href="#" state="HI" full="Hawaii" shape="poly" coords="169,391,170,389,172,388,172,389,170,391,169,391">
    <area href="#" state="HI" shape="poly" coords="176,389,181,390,182,390,183,387,183,385,180,384,177,386,176,389">
    <area href="#" state="HI" shape="poly" coords="199,395,201,400,203,399,204,399,205,400,208,400,208,398,206,398,205,395,203,392,199,395,199,395">
    <area href="#" state="HI" shape="poly" coords="213,402,214,401,218,401,218,401,222,401,222,402,221,404,217,403,213,402">
    <area href="#" state="HI" shape="poly" coords="217,406,218,409,221,407,221,407,220,405,217,405,217,406">
    <area href="#" state="HI" shape="poly" coords="222,405,224,403,227,404,230,405,233,407,233,409,231,410,227,411,226,410,222,405">
    <area href="#" state="HI" shape="poly" coords="234,416,236,415,238,416,243,419,245,421,247,422,248,425,251,428,251,428,248,431,245,431,244,431,242,432,240,435,239,437,237,437,235,435,234,431,235,430,233,426,232,425,232,422,233,422,235,419,236,419,234,418,234,416">
    <area href="#" state="AK" full="Alaska" shape="poly" coords="114,344,114,405,116,406,118,406,119,405,121,405,121,407,125,413,126,414,128,413,129,413,129,410,131,410,131,409,133,408,135,410,135,412,137,413,137,414,140,416,143,420,145,422,146,425,147,428,151,428,155,430,155,434,156,436,155,438,154,440,152,439,152,437,149,436,149,435,148,436,149,437,149,440,148,440,146,440,145,438,146,440,146,441,146,441,143,437,143,435,141,434,141,430,140,430,140,433,140,433,139,430,138,428,137,427,138,431,138,432,137,431,134,427,133,426,132,424,131,422,130,421,130,419,131,419,131,418,129,419,127,417,125,415,122,413,119,411,119,409,119,407,118,409,116,410,113,409,109,407,105,407,104,407,100,404,98,404,96,400,94,400,92,401,92,404,92,402,93,403,92,406,95,404,95,405,92,408,91,408,91,407,90,406,89,407,87,405,85,407,83,408,81,410,77,410,77,408,80,408,80,407,78,407,79,404,80,402,80,401,80,400,84,398,85,399,86,399,86,398,83,397,80,399,77,401,77,404,75,405,72,406,70,408,70,410,71,410,72,411,70,414,65,417,60,420,59,421,54,422,50,423,52,424,51,425,50,426,49,425,46,425,46,427,45,427,45,425,43,426,41,427,38,426,36,428,34,428,32,428,31,429,29,428,27,428,26,428,25,429,24,428,24,427,26,426,31,426,34,425,35,424,38,423,39,422,41,422,42,424,43,423,44,422,47,421,49,420,50,420,50,420,51,420,52,418,55,416,56,414,58,410,59,410,59,407,58,409,56,409,55,407,54,407,53,408,53,410,53,410,51,406,50,407,50,406,50,405,47,405,45,406,43,406,44,404,44,403,44,401,45,401,46,401,45,399,45,396,45,395,44,396,40,396,38,395,38,392,37,390,37,389,38,389,38,387,39,386,38,386,38,386,37,384,38,380,41,378,43,377,44,374,46,374,48,374,48,376,50,376,53,374,53,374,54,375,56,375,57,374,58,371,58,366,56,367,54,368,53,367,50,366,47,366,44,363,44,360,44,359,43,357,41,355,42,354,47,353,48,353,49,354,50,354,50,353,53,353,54,353,55,353,54,355,54,356,56,357,59,359,61,358,59,355,59,353,59,352,56,350,56,350,56,349,56,346,54,342,52,339,54,338,56,338,58,338,61,338,64,335,65,333,67,332,68,332,71,332,73,330,74,330,74,331,78,331,80,329,80,329,83,330,85,332,84,332,85,333,86,332,89,332,89,335,90,336,95,337,100,340,101,339,105,341,107,341,108,340,111,341,114,344">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="31,365,32,368,32,369,30,368,29,366,28,365,26,365,26,363,27,361,28,363,29,364,31,365">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="29,389,32,389,35,390,35,391,34,393,32,393,29,391,29,389">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="14,378,15,380,16,381,15,382,14,380,14,378,14,378">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="4,431,7,430,9,429,11,429,11,431,13,431,14,429,14,428,16,428,18,430,17,431,14,432,12,431,9,431,6,431,5,432,4,431">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="40,428,41,430,42,428,41,428,40,428">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="42,431,43,428,44,429,44,431,42,431">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="59,429,60,430,61,429,60,428,59,429">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="65,420,66,424,68,425,72,422,75,421,74,419,74,417,73,418,71,418,71,417,73,417,76,416,77,415,74,414,75,413,73,414,70,417,66,419,65,420">
    <area href="#" state="AK" shape="poly" coords="96,406,98,404,97,403,95,404,96,406">
    <area href="#" state="FL" full="Florida" shape="poly" coords="548,337,549,343,552,350,556,356,558,361,562,365,565,368,566,370,565,371,565,372,566,377,569,380,571,383,573,387,577,393,578,399,578,407,578,409,578,411,576,413,577,413,576,415,576,417,577,419,575,421,572,422,569,422,569,423,567,424,566,423,565,422,565,421,564,418,562,414,559,413,557,413,556,413,554,410,553,407,551,404,550,404,549,405,548,405,546,401,544,398,542,395,540,392,537,390,539,388,541,384,541,383,538,383,536,383,537,383,539,384,538,387,537,388,536,385,535,381,535,379,536,376,536,369,533,366,533,364,529,363,527,362,526,361,524,359,523,357,521,356,519,353,516,353,514,351,512,351,509,352,509,353,509,354,509,355,507,355,504,357,502,359,499,359,497,360,497,358,495,356,493,356,492,355,486,352,481,350,477,351,473,351,469,353,466,353,466,347,464,346,463,344,463,342,470,341,489,339,494,339,498,339,500,341,501,343,507,343,515,342,530,341,534,341,538,341,538,343,540,344,540,341,539,337,539,336,544,337,548,337">
    <area href="#" state="FL" shape="poly" coords="557,434,558,433,560,433,560,431,562,430,563,431,564,431,564,431,562,432,559,433,557,434,557,434">
    <area href="#" state="FL" shape="poly" coords="566,430,567,431,569,429,573,426,576,423,578,419,578,417,578,415,578,415,577,417,576,420,574,425,571,428,568,428,566,430">
    <area href="#" state="GA" full="Georgia" shape="poly" coords="500,274,497,275,490,275,484,276,484,278,484,279,485,281,487,287,489,295,490,299,491,302,492,308,494,312,495,314,496,317,497,317,497,319,496,323,496,325,496,326,497,329,497,333,497,335,497,336,498,336,498,339,500,341,501,343,507,343,515,342,530,341,534,341,538,341,538,343,540,344,540,341,539,337,539,336,544,337,548,337,547,332,548,325,550,322,549,320,552,315,551,314,551,314,548,314,548,312,547,310,545,308,544,308,542,304,540,299,537,299,536,297,535,295,533,293,532,293,530,290,528,289,524,287,524,287,523,284,522,284,520,280,518,280,515,278,513,277,513,276,514,275,515,274,515,272,514,272,510,273,505,274,500,274">
    <area href="#" state="AL" full="Alabama" shape="poly" coords="453,353,452,342,450,329,450,318,451,296,451,284,451,279,457,278,476,277,484,276,484,278,484,279,485,281,487,287,489,295,490,299,491,302,492,308,494,312,495,314,496,317,497,317,497,319,496,323,496,325,496,326,497,329,497,333,497,335,497,336,498,336,499,339,494,339,489,339,470,341,463,342,463,344,464,346,466,347,467,353,461,355,460,355,461,353,461,353,459,348,458,348,457,351,456,353,455,353,453,353">
    <area href="#" state="NC" full="North Carolina" shape="poly" coords="603,231,605,234,607,239,608,241,609,242,608,242,608,243,608,246,606,247,605,248,605,251,602,252,600,251,599,251,598,251,598,251,598,252,599,252,600,253,599,257,602,257,602,259,604,257,605,257,603,260,601,263,600,263,599,263,597,263,593,265,589,269,587,272,585,277,584,278,581,279,577,281,570,275,560,269,559,269,549,269,546,270,545,267,543,266,531,266,526,267,520,270,515,272,514,272,510,273,505,274,500,274,500,271,501,269,503,269,504,266,507,264,509,263,512,260,516,259,516,257,519,254,520,254,523,252,525,252,527,252,527,250,530,248,530,246,530,243,533,244,539,243,550,242,563,239,578,237,591,234,599,232,603,231">
    <area href="#" state="NC" shape="poly" coords="606,255,608,253,610,251,611,251,611,249,611,245,610,243,609,242,610,242,612,245,612,248,612,251,610,252,608,254,607,255,606,255">
    <area href="#" state="TN" full="Tennessee" shape="poly" coords="505,247,467,251,456,252,453,252,450,252,450,255,444,255,439,256,431,256,431,260,429,265,428,267,428,270,427,272,424,274,425,276,425,279,423,281,429,281,447,279,451,279,457,278,476,277,484,276,490,275,497,275,500,274,500,271,501,269,503,269,504,266,507,264,509,263,512,260,516,259,516,257,519,254,520,254,523,252,525,252,527,252,527,250,530,248,530,246,530,243,529,243,527,245,521,245,512,246,505,247">
    <area href="#" state="RI" full="Rhode Island" shape="poly" coords="633,145,633,142,632,139,632,134,635,134,637,134,639,137,641,140,639,142,638,141,638,143,635,144,633,145">
    <area href="#" state="CT" full="Connecticut" shape="poly" coords="634,145,633,142,632,139,632,134,628,135,612,139,612,141,614,146,614,152,613,154,614,155,617,153,620,151,621,149,622,149,624,149,628,148,634,145">
    <area href="#" state="MA" full="Massachusetts" shape="poly" coords="653,140,654,140,654,139,655,139,656,140,655,141,652,141,653,140">
    <area href="#" state="MA" shape="poly" coords="645,141,647,139,648,139,650,140,648,141,647,142,645,141">
    <area href="#" state="MA" shape="poly" coords="620,125,633,122,635,122,636,119,639,118,641,122,639,125,639,126,641,128,641,128,642,128,644,129,647,134,650,134,651,134,653,132,652,130,650,129,649,129,648,128,649,128,650,128,652,128,653,131,654,132,654,134,651,135,648,137,645,140,644,141,644,140,646,140,646,138,645,136,644,137,643,138,643,140,641,140,639,137,637,134,635,134,632,134,628,135,612,139,611,134,611,127,615,126,620,125">
    <area href="#" state="ME" full="Maine" shape="poly" coords="669,71,671,72,672,75,672,76,671,80,669,80,667,83,663,86,660,85,659,86,658,87,657,88,659,89,658,89,658,92,656,92,656,90,656,89,655,89,653,87,652,88,653,89,653,90,653,91,653,93,653,95,652,96,650,97,650,98,646,101,644,101,644,100,641,103,642,105,641,106,641,110,640,115,638,114,638,112,635,111,635,109,629,92,626,81,628,81,629,81,629,80,629,75,631,72,632,69,631,68,631,63,632,62,632,60,632,59,632,56,633,52,635,46,637,43,638,43,638,43,638,44,639,45,641,46,642,45,642,44,645,42,647,41,647,41,652,43,653,44,659,65,664,65,665,67,665,70,667,72,668,72,668,71,667,71,669,71">
    <area href="#" state="ME" shape="poly" coords="654,92,655,92,656,92,656,94,655,95,654,92">
    <area href="#" state="ME" shape="poly" coords="659,88,660,89,662,87,662,86,660,86,659,88">
    <area href="#" state="NH" shape="poly" coords="639,118,639,117,640,115,638,114,638,112,635,111,635,109,629,92,626,81,626,81,625,83,624,82,623,81,623,83,622,87,622,91,623,93,623,96,621,99,619,100,619,101,620,102,620,108,619,115,619,118,620,119,620,122,620,124,620,125,633,122,635,122,636,119,639,118">
    <area href="#" state="VT" shape="poly" coords="611,127,611,123,609,115,608,115,606,113,607,112,606,110,605,107,605,104,605,100,603,95,602,92,622,87,622,91,623,93,623,96,621,99,619,100,619,101,620,102,620,108,619,115,619,118,620,119,620,122,620,124,620,125,615,126,611,127">
    <area href="#" state="NY" full="New York" shape="poly" coords="600,152,599,152,598,152,596,150,594,146,592,146,590,144,577,147,545,153,539,155,539,149,541,148,542,147,542,146,543,146,545,144,545,143,547,141,548,140,548,140,547,137,545,137,544,133,546,131,549,131,552,129,554,129,559,129,560,130,562,130,563,129,565,128,569,128,570,127,572,125,572,123,574,123,575,122,575,120,575,119,575,118,575,116,575,115,574,115,572,115,572,114,572,112,576,108,577,107,578,105,580,102,582,99,584,98,585,96,587,95,591,95,593,95,597,93,602,92,603,95,605,100,605,104,605,107,606,110,607,112,606,113,608,115,609,115,611,123,611,127,611,134,611,138,612,141,614,146,614,152,613,154,614,155,614,156,612,158,613,158,614,158,614,158,616,155,617,155,618,155,620,155,626,153,628,151,629,150,632,151,629,154,626,155,621,160,620,160,615,161,612,162,611,162,611,160,611,158,611,156,609,155,605,155,603,154,600,152">
    <area href="#" state="NJ" full="New Jersey" shape="poly" coords="600,152,599,155,599,156,597,158,597,160,598,161,598,163,596,164,597,165,597,166,599,167,600,168,602,170,604,171,604,172,602,174,601,176,599,178,598,179,597,179,597,180,596,182,597,184,599,185,603,188,606,188,606,189,605,190,605,191,606,191,608,190,608,186,611,183,613,179,614,175,613,174,613,167,611,164,611,165,609,165,608,165,609,164,611,163,611,162,611,160,611,158,611,156,609,155,605,155,603,154,600,152">
    <area href="#" state="PA" full="Pennsylvania" shape="poly" coords="597,179,598,179,599,178,601,176,602,174,604,172,604,171,602,170,600,168,599,167,597,166,597,165,596,164,598,163,598,161,597,160,597,158,599,156,599,155,600,152,599,152,598,152,596,150,594,146,592,146,590,144,577,147,545,153,539,155,539,149,535,153,534,154,531,156,533,170,534,178,537,191,540,191,549,190,576,185,587,182,593,181,594,180,596,179,597,179">
    <area href="#" state="DE" shape="poly" coords="596,182,597,180,597,179,596,179,594,180,593,182,594,185,596,188,597,196,599,200,602,200,606,199,605,194,604,194,602,192,600,189,599,186,597,185,596,183,596,182">
    <area href="#" state="MD" shape="poly" coords="606,199,602,200,599,200,597,196,596,188,594,185,593,181,587,182,576,185,549,190,550,194,551,197,551,197,552,196,554,194,556,194,557,192,558,191,559,191,561,191,563,189,565,188,566,188,567,188,569,190,571,191,572,192,575,193,575,195,578,196,580,197,581,196,582,197,581,200,581,201,580,203,580,205,580,206,584,207,587,207,589,208,590,208,591,206,590,205,590,203,588,202,587,198,588,194,588,193,587,191,590,188,591,186,591,187,590,188,590,191,590,192,591,192,591,196,590,197,590,200,590,199,591,197,593,199,591,200,591,203,593,205,596,205,597,205,599,209,600,209,600,212,599,215,599,220,599,222,601,222,602,219,602,217,602,212,605,208,606,203,606,199">
    <area href="#" state="MD" shape="poly" coords="595,206,596,208,596,209,596,211,596,206,595,206">
    <area href="#" state="WV" shape="poly" coords="549,190,550,194,551,197,551,197,552,196,554,194,556,194,557,192,558,191,559,191,561,191,563,189,565,188,566,188,567,188,569,190,571,191,572,192,571,195,566,193,563,192,563,196,563,197,562,200,561,200,559,202,559,204,557,204,556,206,555,210,554,210,552,209,551,208,550,208,550,211,548,216,545,224,545,224,545,227,544,228,542,227,540,230,538,229,537,232,530,233,528,234,527,233,525,233,524,230,521,229,520,227,518,224,517,223,515,221,515,221,515,217,516,216,518,216,518,214,518,213,519,209,519,206,521,206,521,207,521,208,523,207,524,206,523,205,523,203,523,202,525,200,526,199,527,199,529,198,531,195,533,193,533,188,533,185,533,182,533,179,533,178,534,177,537,191,540,191,549,190">
    <area href="#" state="VA" full="Virginia" shape="poly" coords="524,230,525,233,527,233,528,234,530,233,532,232,538,229,540,230,542,227,544,228,545,227,545,224,545,224,548,216,550,211,550,208,551,208,552,209,554,210,555,210,556,206,557,204,559,204,559,202,561,200,562,200,563,197,563,196,563,192,566,193,571,195,572,191,575,193,575,195,578,196,580,197,581,196,582,197,581,200,581,201,580,203,580,205,580,206,584,207,585,208,589,209,590,210,593,210,594,212,593,215,594,215,594,217,596,218,596,220,593,219,593,220,594,221,594,221,596,222,596,224,596,225,595,227,595,227,597,227,599,226,600,226,603,231,599,232,591,234,578,237,563,239,550,242,539,243,533,244,530,243,529,243,527,245,521,245,512,246,505,247,507,246,511,244,514,242,514,241,515,239,518,236,521,233,524,230">
    <area href="#" state="KY" full="Kentucky" shape="poly" coords="524,230,521,233,518,236,515,239,514,241,514,242,511,244,507,246,505,247,467,251,456,252,453,252,450,252,450,255,444,255,439,256,431,256,432,255,434,254,435,253,435,251,436,249,435,248,435,246,437,245,439,245,440,245,443,246,444,246,444,245,443,242,443,241,445,240,446,239,448,239,447,238,446,236,448,236,449,233,450,232,455,231,458,231,458,233,460,233,461,230,463,230,464,231,465,232,467,231,467,229,469,227,470,227,470,228,473,228,474,227,474,225,476,222,479,220,480,216,482,216,485,215,487,213,486,212,485,211,485,209,488,209,491,209,493,210,494,213,498,213,499,215,500,215,503,214,505,214,506,215,508,213,509,212,510,212,511,214,512,215,515,216,515,221,515,221,517,223,518,224,520,227,521,229,524,230">
    <area href="#" state="OH" full="Ohio" shape="poly" coords="531,156,526,159,523,161,521,163,518,166,515,167,513,167,509,169,508,169,505,167,501,167,500,166,497,165,494,166,487,167,481,167,482,179,483,188,485,205,485,209,488,209,491,209,493,210,494,213,498,213,499,215,500,215,503,214,505,214,506,215,508,213,509,212,510,212,511,214,512,215,515,217,516,216,518,216,518,214,518,213,519,209,519,206,521,206,521,207,521,208,523,207,524,206,523,205,523,203,523,202,525,200,526,199,527,199,529,198,531,195,533,193,533,188,533,185,533,182,533,179,533,178,534,178,533,170,531,156">
    <area href="#" state="MI" full="Michigan" shape="poly" coords="422,74,423,73,425,72,428,69,430,68,431,69,427,73,424,74,422,75,422,74">
    <area href="#" state="MI" shape="poly" coords="484,98,485,99,487,99,488,98,485,96,484,96,483,97,484,98">
    <area href="#" state="MI" shape="poly" coords="506,143,503,137,502,131,500,128,498,127,497,128,494,129,493,133,491,135,490,136,489,135,490,129,491,127,491,125,493,124,493,116,491,115,491,114,490,113,491,112,491,113,491,111,490,110,489,107,487,107,484,107,480,104,478,104,477,104,476,104,474,103,473,104,470,106,470,108,471,108,473,109,473,110,471,110,470,110,468,111,468,113,468,114,468,118,466,119,465,119,465,116,467,115,467,113,467,113,465,113,464,116,462,117,461,118,461,119,461,119,461,122,459,122,459,122,460,125,459,128,458,131,458,135,458,136,458,137,458,138,458,140,460,145,462,149,463,152,463,156,462,161,460,164,460,166,458,168,457,169,461,169,476,167,481,167,481,167,487,167,494,166,498,165,497,164,497,164,499,161,500,159,500,156,501,155,502,155,502,152,503,149,504,150,504,151,505,151,506,150,506,143">
    <area href="#" state="MI" shape="poly" coords="410,95,412,95,414,94,416,92,416,92,417,92,421,91,423,89,426,88,426,87,428,85,429,84,430,83,431,81,434,80,438,79,439,80,439,80,436,81,435,83,433,84,433,86,431,88,431,90,431,90,432,89,434,87,436,89,437,89,440,89,440,90,442,92,444,94,446,94,448,93,449,95,450,95,451,94,452,94,453,93,456,91,458,90,463,89,467,89,468,87,470,87,470,92,470,92,472,92,473,92,478,91,479,90,479,90,479,95,482,98,483,98,484,99,483,99,482,99,479,98,478,99,476,99,474,100,473,100,468,99,464,99,464,101,458,101,457,102,455,104,455,105,455,105,453,104,450,106,449,106,449,104,448,104,447,107,446,110,443,116,442,116,441,115,440,107,437,107,437,104,428,103,425,102,419,100,413,99,410,95">
    <area href="#" state="WY" full="Wyoming" shape="poly" coords="257,119,249,118,226,116,214,114,194,111,179,109,178,117,175,135,171,157,170,164,169,173,174,174,186,176,192,176,207,178,234,181,252,182,255,150,257,132,257,119">
    <area href="#" state="MT" full="Montana" shape="poly" coords="259,104,260,95,261,77,262,66,263,56,240,53,219,51,197,48,174,44,161,41,137,37,134,52,137,57,135,61,137,64,139,65,142,73,144,75,145,76,147,77,147,78,142,91,142,93,144,95,145,95,148,93,149,92,150,93,149,97,152,106,154,107,155,108,156,110,155,112,156,115,157,116,158,113,161,113,163,115,164,114,167,114,170,116,172,115,173,113,175,113,176,113,176,116,178,117,179,109,194,111,214,114,226,116,249,118,257,119,259,107,259,104">
    <area href="#" state="ID" full="Idaho" shape="poly" coords="102,143,105,130,108,117,110,114,111,110,110,108,109,108,108,107,108,107,109,104,112,101,113,100,114,99,114,97,115,96,118,92,121,89,121,86,119,84,117,81,118,74,120,62,124,47,126,38,127,35,137,37,134,52,137,57,135,61,137,64,139,65,142,73,144,75,145,76,147,77,147,78,142,91,142,93,144,95,145,95,148,93,149,92,150,93,149,97,152,106,154,107,155,108,156,110,155,112,156,115,157,116,158,113,161,113,163,115,164,114,167,114,170,116,172,115,173,113,175,113,176,113,176,116,178,117,175,135,172,157,168,156,162,155,155,154,146,152,137,151,131,149,124,148,117,146,102,143">
    <area href="#" state="WA" full="Washington" shape="poly" coords="68,19,71,20,78,22,84,23,98,28,116,32,127,35,126,38,124,47,120,62,118,74,118,81,107,79,96,76,85,76,85,75,81,77,77,77,76,75,75,76,71,75,71,74,67,73,66,73,63,72,62,74,57,73,53,70,53,69,53,64,52,61,49,61,48,59,47,59,45,57,44,58,42,56,42,54,44,53,46,50,44,50,44,47,47,47,45,44,44,40,44,38,44,32,43,29,44,23,47,23,48,25,50,27,53,29,56,30,58,30,60,32,62,32,64,32,64,30,65,29,67,29,67,29,67,31,65,31,65,32,66,33,67,35,68,37,69,36,69,35,68,35,68,32,68,31,68,30,68,29,69,26,68,24,67,20,67,20,68,19">
    <area href="#" state="WA" shape="poly" coords="61,23,62,23,62,24,64,23,65,23,66,24,65,26,65,26,65,28,64,28,63,26,63,26,62,27,61,26,61,23">
   
    <area href="#" state="CA" full="California" shape="poly" coords="99,296,102,295,104,293,104,291,101,291,101,290,101,289,101,285,103,284,105,282,105,278,107,276,108,275,110,273,112,272,112,271,111,270,110,269,110,266,107,262,108,260,106,257,95,241,81,220,65,195,56,182,57,177,62,158,68,135,58,133,48,130,39,127,34,125,26,123,20,122,20,125,19,131,15,139,13,141,13,142,11,143,11,146,10,148,12,151,13,154,14,156,14,161,13,164,12,167,11,170,13,173,14,176,17,180,17,182,17,185,17,185,17,187,21,191,20,194,20,195,20,197,20,203,21,205,23,207,25,207,26,209,24,212,23,213,22,213,22,216,22,218,24,221,26,225,26,228,27,230,30,235,31,236,32,239,32,239,32,241,32,242,31,248,30,249,32,251,35,251,38,253,41,254,43,254,45,257,47,260,48,262,51,263,54,264,56,266,56,268,55,268,55,269,57,269,59,269,62,273,65,276,65,278,67,281,67,283,67,290,68,291,74,292,89,294,99,296">
    <area href="#" state="CA" shape="poly" coords="35,259,36,260,36,261,34,261,33,260,33,259,35,259">
    <area href="#" state="CA" shape="poly" coords="37,259,38,258,40,260,42,261,41,261,38,261,37,260,37,259">
    <area href="#" state="CA" shape="poly" coords="52,273,53,275,53,275,55,276,55,275,54,274,53,272,52,272,52,273">
    <area href="#" state="CA" shape="poly" coords="50,279,52,282,53,283,52,284,51,282,50,279">
    <area href="#" state="AZ" full="Arizona" shape="poly" coords="100,296,98,297,98,298,98,299,112,306,120,312,131,318,143,326,152,327,172,330,173,320,176,301,181,262,184,239,165,237,146,233,122,229,119,242,119,242,118,245,116,245,115,242,113,242,113,241,112,241,111,242,110,242,110,248,110,248,109,258,108,260,107,262,110,266,110,269,111,270,112,271,112,272,110,273,108,275,107,276,105,278,105,282,103,284,101,285,101,289,101,290,101,291,104,291,104,293,102,295,100,296">
    <area href="#" state="NV" full="Nevada" shape="poly" coords="102,143,117,146,124,148,131,149,137,151,136,155,133,167,131,182,129,189,128,199,125,211,123,221,122,230,119,242,119,242,118,245,116,245,115,242,113,242,113,241,112,241,111,242,110,242,110,248,110,248,109,258,108,260,106,257,95,241,81,220,65,195,56,182,57,177,62,158,68,135,92,141,102,143">
    <area href="#" state="UT" full="Utah" shape="poly" coords="184,240,165,237,146,233,122,229,123,221,125,211,128,199,129,189,131,182,133,167,136,155,137,151,146,152,155,154,162,155,168,156,172,157,170,164,169,173,174,174,186,176,193,176,191,192,188,209,185,229,185,237,184,240">
    <area href="#" state="CO" full="Colorado" shape="poly" coords="272,248,275,201,276,185,252,182,234,181,207,178,192,176,191,192,188,209,185,229,185,237,184,240,209,242,236,246,260,248,264,248,272,248">
    <area href="#" state="NM" full="New Mexico" shape="poly" coords="206,327,205,323,211,324,232,326,253,327,254,310,257,270,259,256,260,256,260,248,236,246,209,242,184,240,181,262,176,301,173,320,172,330,183,331,184,324,196,326,206,327">
    <area href="#" state="OR" full="Oregon" shape="poly" coords="102,143,105,130,108,117,110,114,111,110,110,108,109,108,108,107,108,107,109,104,112,101,113,100,114,99,114,97,115,96,118,92,121,89,121,86,119,84,118,81,107,79,96,76,85,76,85,75,81,77,77,77,76,75,75,76,71,75,71,74,67,73,66,73,63,72,62,74,57,73,53,70,53,69,53,64,52,61,49,61,48,59,47,59,42,60,41,65,38,72,36,77,32,87,28,97,22,106,20,108,20,114,19,119,20,122,26,123,34,125,39,127,48,130,58,133,68,135">
    <area href="#" state="OR" shape="poly" coords="102,143,68,135,92,141,102,143">
    <area href="#" state="ND" full="North Dakota" shape="poly" coords="342,107,341,101,341,96,339,86,338,80,338,77,336,73,336,65,337,63,335,59,314,59,300,58,281,57,263,56,262,66,261,77,260,95,259,104,300,107,342,107">
    <area href="#" state="SD" full="South Dakota" shape="poly" coords="343,162,343,161,341,159,343,155,344,152,341,150,341,148,342,146,344,146,344,141,344,119,343,117,340,115,339,113,339,112,341,111,342,110,342,107,300,107,259,104,259,107,257,119,257,132,255,151,266,152,281,152,294,153,311,154,319,154,320,155,324,158,325,158,328,157,331,157,333,157,334,158,338,158,340,160,341,161,341,163,342,163,343,162">
    <area href="#" state="NE" full="Nebraska" shape="poly" coords="352,194,353,195,353,197,354,200,356,203,352,203,320,203,291,201,275,200,276,185,252,182,255,151,266,152,281,152,294,153,311,154,319,154,320,155,324,158,325,158,328,157,331,157,333,157,334,158,338,158,340,160,341,161,341,163,342,163,344,162,344,167,347,172,347,176,349,178,349,182,350,185,350,190,352,194">
    <area href="#" state="IA" full="Iowa" shape="poly" coords="411,161,411,162,413,162,413,163,414,164,417,167,417,169,417,171,416,174,415,176,413,177,412,177,408,179,407,180,407,182,407,182,409,183,409,186,407,188,407,188,407,191,406,191,404,192,404,193,404,194,404,196,401,193,400,191,395,192,387,192,369,193,359,193,353,194,352,194,350,190,350,185,349,182,349,178,347,176,347,172,344,167,344,162,342,161,341,159,343,155,344,152,341,150,341,148,342,146,343,146,352,146,388,146,401,146,404,145,404,148,406,149,406,150,404,152,404,155,407,158,408,158,410,158,411,161">

    </map>
```

---

This is also a useful site when creating area maps:

<strike>http://www.image-mapper.com/</strike>

Replaced with (201019): *(Thank you, Jurgen)*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8138679/1447509

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction i will look into imagemapster and i hope that it will give me what i am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`<map>` and `<area>` tags themselves are already transparent - in fact, `<map>` isn't visualized at all; it just defines the hover/click areas for the image/svg element that uses this particular map.

If you want areas to be "colored", you need to recolor the underlying image *or* use external libraries.

Comment: the only problem with making the img a different color is i am going to link the page with a database that will tell the map what color the room needs to be! but thanks for the comments!

Comment: @RileyMclaughlin you're welcome. For coloring, you probably need to look into the links of the other comment you've got.